# Testing an object imported with curl with mocha/enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

in some part of my code i have this code layout out (which imports a javascript code into my function):

```
curl(Utils.getPHPUrl() + '/generic/common/js/gn_tooltip.js');
```

But when testing it (using mocha/enzyme/chai), an error is thrown, which says:

> gn_tooltip is not defined

I tried using the same curl in my test file, with no success, does someone know how can i import the same script and make it work on my tests?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i could not find a way to test curl with enzyme/mocha, but as we use istanbul to check the coverage, i made it ignore some parts of the code that utilize the js file from curl.
I am almost sure that it is possible to unit test a react component that used curl, but i just don't know how atm.